# Sharepoint user permissions on subsite

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In our Sharepoint 2010 solution we have a list extension that allows users to create their own subsite. This worked without any problems in our previous version of Sharepoint (2007).

Since the switchover to SP 2010 we notice that it takes a few minutes for setting the appropriate user permissions on the subsite. This would be a security risk.

What could be causing this problem ?

Code for list item added: http://pastebin.com/idxg5a0p

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and I see some possible improvements:

1. Use BreakRoleInheritance(false) - lines 64,86. Then you can remove following role assignments removing loops.
2. You can break role inheritace of created web directly when adding the web (use true on line 34 of your code).

   1. I think you could remove AllowUnsafeUpdates as it is not generally necessary in event receivers.

That should help.

Comment: Thank you for this! The time for setting permissions has reduced a lot. Creating the subsite itself though takes about 20 seconds, can this be reduced?